React calling API requests before axios sets auth headers
I am trying to set up AuthContext is react and running into a problem where react calls an API before axios sets the auth headers in the request. This is causes API failures on first render missing authentication parameters.
I will provide smaller examples of AuthContext, AuthService, and App
AuthContext
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import AuthService from "./authService";

// Hardcoded token for testing
const hardcodedToken = "your-hardcoded-token-here";

// Create the AuthContext
const AuthContext = createContext(null);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const checkIfLogged = useCallback(async () => {
    const token = hardcodedToken;

    if (token) {
      setToken(token);
      setIsAuthenticated(true);

      // Set Axios defaults and mark auth as ready
      authService.setAxiosDefaults(token);
    } else {
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
      authService.TODOLogout();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfLogged();
  }, [checkIfLogged]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, isAuthenticated }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

AuthService
import axios from "axios";

class AuthService {
  constructor(authRedirectUrlPrefix) {
    this.authRedirectUrlPrefix = authRedirectUrlPrefix;
  }


  /** Set default axios headers and interceptors */
  setAxiosDefaults(token) {
    debugger;
    // Pass auth token in each request
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        return response; // Ignore successful responses
      },
      (error) => {
        // If response contains auth error, redirect to login
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          this.redirectToLogout(false);
        }
        return error;
      }
    );
  }
}

export default AuthService;

App
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";

import Header from "./layout/Header";
import store from "./store";
import { Home } from "./components/Home";

import { AuthContextProvider } from "./auth/AuthContext";
import { ApiContextProvider } from "./context/ApiContext";

const mdTheme = createTheme();

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
        <ApiContextProvider>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <ThemeProvider theme={mdTheme}>
              <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Header />
                <Box
                  component="main"
                  sx={{
                    backgroundColor: (theme) =>
                      theme.palette.mode === "light"
                        ? theme.palette.grey[300]
                        : theme.palette.grey[900],
                    flexGrow: 1,
                    height: "100vh",
                    overflow: "auto",
                  }}
                >
                  <Toolbar />
                  <Container maxWidth="lg" sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 3 }}>
                    <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                      <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                    </Switch>
                  </Container>
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </ApiContextProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

Now given all of that set up, what's happening is my react app calls this first api request before the auth headers are set. I can tell because I added a debugger here and this is hit first when reloading the app.
import React, { createContext, useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
// import config from "../config";

const ApiClient = {
  getData: async () => {
    // debugger;
    const response = await axios.get(/demo/data);
    return response.data;
  },
};

// Create the API Client Context
export const ApiClientContext = createContext(ApiClient);

export const useApiClient = () => {
  return useContext(ApiClientContext);
};

// Provider component to wrap around your app
export const ApiContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return ApiClient;
  }, []);

  return (
    <ApiContextProvider.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ApiContextProvider.Provider>
  );
};


Where does authService get initialized?

It seems like the cause of the issue is that the first request is being made in the short time span between when token is initialized to null and it is updated to a proper value. This is a perfectly valid scenario. To avoid it we could fetch const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth(); and wait for isAuthenticated to become true before making the request.
Below is one approach to do that.
const ApiClient = (isAuthenticated) => ({
  getData: async () => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const response = await axios.get(/demo/data);
      return response.data;
    } else {
      // don't call the endpoint when not authenticated
      return undefined;
    }
  }),
};

export const ApiContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return ApiClient(isAuthenticated);
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <ApiContextProvider.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ApiContextProvider.Provider>
  );
};

